# jquery star rating callback

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I've been trying to use this jquery star rating plugin: http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/#tab-Overview. I'm trying to get the value of the star once it's clicked but I've been having no luck. I wasn't sure where to include the following callback they suggest:

```
$('.auto-submit-star').rating({
    callback: function(value, link){
        alert(value);
    }
});
```

I've tried sticking it around in the code but I get no alert when I click a star. Thanks!!

Comment: what kind of answer do you expect to get? This code works at http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/#tab-Testing, so debug yours

Answer (score 5):

```
$(function(){
    $('input[type=radio].star').rating();
});
```

Remove the above lines from the jquery.rating.js, and you are all set. 
I suppose I don't need to explain why as it's intuitive =)

Comment: You are right about it. It's not clear that if you want to use callback you need to define another class and copy all star csses to make the script working or edit original lib to remove lines as mensioned above. User should start the rating script, not the lib itself.

Answer (score 3):

You need to *change* the class on the radio buttons from `star` to `auto-submit-star`, don't just add `auto-submit-star` to the existing class of star on the radio buttons. For example mine looks like this:

```
<input name="star1" type="radio" class="auto-submit-star" value="1"/>
```

Comment: That's it exactly. Giving the inputs the default "star" AND "auto-star-submit" hinders the callback from being attached to the rating stars.

Answer (score 1):

Did you give your radio buttons the class name of `auto-submit-star`?

```
<input type="radio" name="whatever" class="auto-submit-star" />
```

`$('.auto-submit-star')` selects all radio buttons with a class of `auto-submit-star`, and then sets up the `rating` plugin.

---

On the other hand, it seems that you might be doing it before `DOM ready`. In case you don't know what that is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('.auto-submit-star').rating({
        callback: function(value, link){
            alert(value);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: If it was true - then he wouldn't even see any rating starts. Why he said that he sees them, but haven't callback invoked.

Comment: @Joseph Thanks for replying! I tried giving the radio button the `auto-submit-star` but there's still nothing when I click.

Comment: @sad-ducky: Is it possible that you're not waiting for `DOM ready`? See my updated answer.

Comment: thanks for the updated answer! it still didn't work, though, so i just decided to scrap the plugin and write my own rating system. thanks again, though!

Answer (score 1):

https://code.google.com/p/jquery-star-rating-plugin/issues/detail?id=21
refer to this: **You must use a selector other than ".star"**

Answer (score 0):

Open your browser's developer tools and look in the console log; are there any warnings or error messages? If so, something's wrong in your code. Otherwise, Jospeh's answer is likely correct and your selector (`$('.auto-submit-star')`) isn't selecting anything.

Comment: I checked but there weren't any warnings/errors about the javascript, just a few css errors.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's very Old POST but my experience may help someone.
I too had the same issue. but able to solve it after generating the code through Ajax, and then at Success callback i invoked the rating plugin. It worked for me.
I think it does not detect the class which is created on the DOM.